# SetColor of a material with hexadecimal value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I set the color of a material of a shader graph with a hexadecimal value?

```
public MeshRenderer mat;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        mat.material.SetColor ("Color_B10F9E01", "3F7232");
    }
```

Comment: Unity has documentation for this, see: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should also work:

```cs
mat.material.SetColor("Color_B10F9E01", new Color32(0xFF, 0x3F, 0x72, 0x32));
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the string to a [Color](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html) using [ColorUtility.TryParseHTMLString](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString.html), then pass the color in `mat.material.SetColor`. For example:

```cs
    public MeshRenderer mat;

    void Start()
    {
        if (ColorUtility.TryParseHTMLString("#3F7232"), out Color color)
        {
            mat.material.SetColor ("Color_B10F9E01", color);
        }
    }
```